# Twitter bootstrap split dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a navbar and I have a caret next to dropdown menu.

In current code, if user clicks `Operations` text or caret, dropdown menu is opened. But I need this:

- If user clicks `Operations` link, I want user to go to my `/operations/` page.
- If user clicks to the caret, dropdown menu will be visible. If user click one of the elements of dropdown menu, user will be redirected to related page.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/UtDqm/2/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <li class="dropdown" id="myTools">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#myTools">
        Operations
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/mypage1/">MyPage 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mypage2/">MyPage 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</div>
```

In Twitter bootstrap documentation it is noted how to create split button dropdowns [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns). I don't want to use buttons. Is it possible to have split behaviour without using buttons. Just with links?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap the caret in the `dropdown-toggle` and add a normal `href` to the operations text? See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UtDqm/5/)

Comment: @JoshuaM same behaviour like Stevie's answer. This works but the caret goes to the next line in navbar. [image link](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/4656/oper1.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the `a` style set to be `display: block`? Thats all I can think of, as it [works fine for me.](http://i.imgur.com/muE2sMI.png)

Comment: No I didn't set to display:block. Which anchor?

Comment: I mean do you have somewhere in your stylesheet a style defined like `a { display: block }`? This could be pushing the caret down onto the next like as the two `<a>` tags round the text and caret are being forced onto new lines. Is there anywhere I could view your working code?

Comment: Updated my answer, the bootstrap style for the `<a>` tags are `display:block` as Joshua mentioned. If you override them to `display:inline-block;` it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Couldn't you just split the Operations link into a new `<a>` tag?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <li class="dropdown" id="myTools">
    <a href="/operations/" style="display:inline-block;padding-right:0px;">Operations</a>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#myTools"  style="display:inline-block;padding-left:0px;">
      <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="/mypage1/">MyPage 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="/mypage2/">MyPage 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</div>
```

Comment: This works but the caret goes to the next line in navbar. [image](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/4656/oper1.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_blank" class="btn btn-link">Action</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/mypage1/">MyPage 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mypage2/">MyPage 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UtDqm/6/