# Bootstrap 3 Split Dropdown in Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, split

I am using a navbar with a dropdown but I want to make it work like this:

- When the text is clicked, a link is followed
- When the caret is clicked, the dropdown opens/closes

[image: desired result]

I don't want to use buttons (or a button group), only a dropdown. I tried:

- using two separate < a > tags but they appear one below the other:

[image: two separate < a > tags]

- make the two < a > tags display:inline but that puts them next to each other but not aligned with the rest of the navbar:

[image: inline tags]

The question was already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963342/twitter-bootstrap-split-dropdown) in 2013 but the solutions given don't work with Boostrap 3.